# Separate edge arrows in python/networkx directed graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I would like to obtain something similar to this:

[image]

using the python library [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html). I can generate a similar directed graph using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge('1','2')
G.add_edge('1','3')
G.add_edge('3','2')
G.add_edge('3','4')
G.add_edge('4','3')

nx.draw(G, node_color='w', edgecolors='k', width=2.0, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

However, the arrows between the nodes 3 and 4 are superimposed, and it just looks as a single arrow with two heads. Would it be possible to separate them slightly, in order to make more evident the fact that there are two edges over there and not just one? (I know that it can be done using pygraphviz, but I am trying to do it using matplotlib).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked the networkx drawing utilities some time ago to work around this and several other issues I have had. The package is called [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph), and supports drawing of `networkx` and `igraph` graph structures (as well as simple edge lists).
It uses matplotlib under the hood, and exposes the created artists so that it easy to manipulate them further even if there is not in-built functionality to do so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412323/separate-edge-arrows-in-python-networkx-directed-graph
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import netgraph

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge('1','2')
G.add_edge('1','3')
G.add_edge('3','2')
G.add_edge('3','4')
G.add_edge('4','3')

netgraph.draw(G, node_color='w', edge_color='k', edge_width=2.0, node_labels={str(ii) : str(ii) for ii in range(1,5)})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I finally switched to pygraphviz because it adds much more control (even too much...) on the layout of the graph, but I just checked your library and I must say you have done a great job! So, even if probably I will not use it in the end, this answer definitely answers my question!

Comment: @Tropilio If you don't mind me asking, what deters you from using netgraph? Trying to find out in what areas I need to improve the project.

Comment: To be frank, I haven't had the time to test out netgraph enough to answer. I switched to pygraphviz some days ago because the 'neato' layout is already [almost good for my purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61425817/force-nodes-positions-on-concentric-circles-in-graphviz-graph). I am now tinkering around to have a good result using pygraphviz, but if you can give me some suggestion on how to achieve that using netgraph, I'll give it a try.

Comment: There are two parts to plotting graphs. 1) computing a layout for the node positions (and possibly for the edge paths), and 2) actually drawing the nodes and edges on a canvas. `netgraph` focuses on step 2) and allows you to specify node positions via the `node_positions` parameter. So you can compute a graphviz/neato node layout with `networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout` and then pass that into netgraph.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a [`MultiDiGraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/classes.multidigraph.html) for multiple edges between two nodes:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_edge('1','2')
G.add_edge('1','3')
G.add_edge('3','2')
G.add_edge('3','4')
G.add_edge('4','3')
```

To visualise the network you could use Graphviz which does display parallel edges. You could write the graph in `dot` and display the graph with [`graphviz.Source`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html):

```
from networkx.drawing import nx_pydot
from graphviz import Source

nx_pydot.write_dot(G, 'multig.dot')
Source.from_file('multig.dot')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this unfortunately it's not solving my problem... as I stated in my question, I am trying to plot using matplotlib.

Comment: As far as I know, for multigraphs you'll need graphviz @Tropilio

Comment: There is [pygraphviz_layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.pygraphviz_layout.html#networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.pygraphviz_layout), but I from the times I've tried it it just overlaps all parallel edges @Tropilio

Comment: Yea, I just tried and I basically see no difference... Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion.