# How to force nodes on specific circles in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I am attempting to use graphviz to produce a graph where the nodes are distributed on concentric circles.

The immediate solution would be to use `twopi` as a layout engine; the issue is that in `twopi` the nodes are distributed on the circles depending on their distance from the root nodes. Also, if those root nodes are not connected, only the first one of them will be used as root.

In my case I want to dictate the circle. So, for example, that I could have a node on the fifth circle being directly connected to one of the nodes on the first circle.

Is there a way to do so?

I also tried to work with `circo`, but there's no way to set concentric circles with that one, apparently.

Notes:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61425817/force-nodes-positions-on-concentric-circles-in-graphviz-graph) is not a duplicate: I'm not trying to force the nodes' position. I'm only trying to force their distance from the center. I still want graphviz to calculate their ideal position along that circle.

**EDIT 1**

I've been asked to provide a MWE so here we are.

The exact thing I'm trying to replicate is a "sociogram", and this is how it should appear:

[image]

Since we are talking about a MWE I made this simplier graph, that I'm trying to replicate using graphviz:

[image]

As you see I dictated A and B to be on the first circle, and F to be on the third one despite actually being one "step" away from both A and B.

This is the code I'm working on (colours added for readability):

```
graph {

normalize = true

a [root = true, shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue"]
b [root = true, shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue"]
c [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue"]
d [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue"]
e [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue"]
f [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue"]
g [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue"]
h [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue"]

a -- c
a -- d
a -- f
c -- e
b -- f
b -- g
b -- h
g -- h

}
```

I run it through the command `dot -Ktwopi -Tpng mwe.dot > mwe.png`.

Result:

[image]

Now: I can't even understand if A and B are actually being taken as root or what. But whatever: F goes in the middle of everything because it's connected both to A and B. I want it to be on the furthest ring. Also: G and H end up being at the same distance from B, while I want G to be on the second ring and H to be on third.

It'd be nice to have the rings to actually be drawn behind the graph, as in the pictures I provided. That would add debug clarity, also.

**EDIT 2 (20/06/2023)**

@sroush was able to solve a big part of the issue via the technique he abundantly explained in his reply. Also, his solution demonstrates that graphviz is excellent for this task because this way the output ends up making nodes' clusters evident, which is the whole point of me trying to produce a sociogram this way.

I still have a few issues that I took a full day to experiment with, so that I could nail them down as much as I could.

First of all: sroush's output contained edges which overlapped on nodes. I easily solved this by adding the `splines=true` attribute to the graph. Graphviz reverts to straight lines in case nodes touch themselves. Which is something that occurs quite frequently, at the moment. I'm currently solving the problem by scaling down the size of nodes and using the `overlap = vpsc` graph option. For instance, this code:

```
digraph {       
graph [root="_root", splines=true, overlap = vpsc]

AI [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightblue", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 1]
AB [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightblue", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 2]
AD [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightblue", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 1]
MB [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightblue", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 2]
ZA [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightblue", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 3]
FG [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightcoral", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 3]
LB [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightcoral", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 1]
LN [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightcoral", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 4]
ST [shape = circle, style = filled, fillcolor = "lightcoral", width = 0.45, fontsize="12.0", fixedsize = true, rank = 3]

AI -> AB[dir = both, color = "green", label="100%", fontsize="10.0", labelfloat = true]
AI -> MB[dir = both, color = "black", label="33%", fontsize="10.0", labelfloat = true]
AI -> LB[dir = both, color = "black", label="66%", fontsize="10.0", labelfloat = true]
AB -> AD[dir = both, color = "black", label="100%", fontsize="10.0", labelfloat = true]
AD -> ZA[dir = both, color = "green", label="33%", fontsize="10.0", labelfloat = true]
AD -> FG[dir = both, color = "green", label="66%", fontsize="10.0", labelfloat = true]
MB -> LB[dir = both, color = "green", label="100%", fontsize="10.0", labelfloat = true]
LB -> ST[dir = both, color = "green", label="33%", fontsize="10.0", labelfloat = true]

}
```

Produces this graph:

[image: splines activated]

As you see I turned the graph into a digraph and added the colours and labels which are present in the sociogram picture I provided above.

All is fine at the moment, besides labels being formatted quite horribly, but I'll work on that. We'll see what happens if the graph becomes more cluttered than that.

The main issue at the moment is that sroush's code only works for less than 10 nodes. If I try to add a tenth one, even if it is not linked to any other node, I get this error on the terminal:

```
gvpr: 
 -- null reference aNode in expression aNode.name
```

And I don't know how to proceed at this point.

Comment: Maybe - Can you provide some reasonable set of starting data & current version of Graphviz input file.

Comment: My experience is that if you want to draw a picture in which you want to have a strong control of the position of text and shape. Using drawing tool like microsoft visio is much more convenient than graphviz dot. I think your picture can be done within 2 hours but with graphviz it guess it will take you 4 hours or more to search the syntax to place the shape.

Comment: Bug fixes made available

Comment: Greetings @sroush. The code now works for 10+ nodes, but it'll place them in the wrong circles. I submitted a dot file and graphviz's export in a comment here: https://gist.github.com/steveroush/788d45ce9cfdb1f27d45b6e9b08e4242. Sorry I can't help in writing the gvpr code, I really don't know anything of that language :(

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be real challenge for the Graphviz toolset, but the following gets pretty close.

**twopi** does not explicitly use the term *ranking* to describe it's layout scheme (other that having a **ranksep** attribute), but we will use the term **rank** to discuss **twopi**.
While **dot** normally performs ranking based on *longest* distances, by default, **twopi** does ranking based on *shortest* distances from the **root** node to each other node.  This can only be modified by setting edge **weight=0**, similar to dot's **constraint=false**.  See https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/weight/

To accomplish the goal requires:

- arranging the nodes around an empty center (as your goal images show), by adding an invisible (or very small) node and set it to root. (the pre-processor step will add this root node if necessary)
- adding a new **rank** attribute to *each* node (this is legal, the Graphviz commands happily ignore unknown attributes)
- using a pre-processor written in **gvpr** to adjust the graph.  It:

  - creates the new, invisible **root** node if necessary
  - adds invisible nodes and edges to "push" the nodes "out" to the desired **rank**
  - sets **weight=0** on any edges that shorten the root-to-node rank/distance.  This causes the edge to be ignored for ranking purposes
- running the pre-processor result though **twopi**
- running the **twopi** output through a post-processor (again in **gvpr**) that will add the concentric circles to the graph
- finally, running the output of the post-processor through **neato -n2** (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords) to actually produce a viewable graph
- whew!

---

An improved version of **setTwopiRanks.gvpr** is located here: https://gist.github.com/steveroush/788d45ce9cfdb1f27d45b6e9b08e4242
An improved version of **twopiCircles.gvpr** is located here: https://gist.github.com/steveroush/aca4cb434042bb67c0eba394c3456d24

---

The pre-processor.  Save as **setTwopiRanks.gvpr**:

```
BEGIN{
  graph_t Root;
  node_t  aNode, center, ID[];
  string  Rank[], centerName;
  int     rnk, nxtID=0, skip[];

  void addInodesandedges(node_t C, node_t toNode, int ranks) {
    int     r, skipTo;
    node_t  n1,n2;
    edge_t  iEdge;
    //string  tmps;
    skipTo=skip[toNode];
    n1=center;
    print("//  ADDING: ", toNode.name, "  ranks: ", ranks);
    for (r=1; r<=ranks; r++) {
      print("// top of loop");
      if (skipTo>=r) {
        print("// skipping: ", toNode.name,"  ",r);
        continue;
      }
      print("// not skipping - continue");
      if (r<ranks) {
        n2 = node(Root, "__"+toNode.name + "_" +(string)r);
        n2.shape="point";
        n2.style="invis";
        n2.label="";
      } else {
        n2=toNode;
      }
      iEdge=edge(n1, n2, "");
      iEdge.style="invis";
      iEdge.color="red";
      n1=n2;
    }
  }
}
BEG_G{
  Root=$G;
  $tvtype = TV_ne;  // all nodes before edges
  centerName=aget(Root,"root");
  if (centerName=="") {
    centerName="__ROOT__";
  }
}
N{
  if (!(hasAttr($, "rank") && $.rank!="")) {
    printf(2, "Error: missing rank attribute (%s), exiting\n", $.name);
    exit(9);
  }
  ID[++nxtID]=$;
  $.id=nxtID;  // yuck
  Rank[0+$.rank]+=(string)nxtID + "|";
}
E{
  int delta;
  string tmps;
  delta=(int)$.head.rank-(int)$.tail.rank;
  if (delta>1) {
    print("// hopped ranks: ", $.name, "  ", $.tail.rank,"  ",$.head.rank);
    $.weight=0;
  } else if (delta==1) {
    print("// EXISTING EDGE ranks: ", $.name, "  ", $.tail.rank,"  ",$.head.rank);
    //tmps=$.head.id + "|" + (string)$.head.rank;
    //skip[tmps]=1;
    skip[$.head]=(int)$.head.rank;  // good through this rank (I hope)
    print("//  skip: ", $.head.name,"  ",skip[$.head]);
  }
}
BEG_G{

  int cnt,t;
  string tok[int];
  center = node($, centerName);
  center.shape="point";
  center.style="invis";
  center.label="";
  //center.root="true";  //centerName;
  for(Rank[rnk]) {
    print("//  Ordered: ", rnk, "  ", Rank[rnk]);
    cnt=tokens(Rank[rnk], tok,"|");
    for (tok[t]) {
      aNode=ID[tok[t]];
      print("// tok: ", tok[t], "  ", aNode.name);
      //  if (rnk==1){
      addInodesandedges(center, aNode, rnk);
      //  }
    }
  }
}
```

The post-processor.  Save as **twopiCircles.gvpr**:

```
//
//  add circles to twopi graph
//
BEGIN{
  node_t  center;
  float x[], y[];
  int i, j, l, max, rsCnt, maxRankSepPt, maxRSPindx, wantOffset;
  string rankSep[int];
  int    RS, rankSepPt[int];
  string POS, st, tok[int];

  int idistance(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2) {
    int d;
    d=(int)sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
    return d;  // points
  }
}
BEG_G{
  string centerName;
  max=0;
  centerName=aget($G,"root");
  if (centerName=="") {
    switch (ARGC) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
      centerName=ARGV[ARGC-1];
      break;
    default:
      printf(2, "Error: missing \"root\" value on command line, exiting\n");
      exit (1);
      break;
    }
  }
  center = node($, centerName);  // 1st or 3rd argument
  if (center==NULL) {
    printf(2, "Error: unknown node (%s), exiting\n", centerName);
    exit(9);
  }
  if (!hasAttr(center, "pos")) {
    printf(2, "Error:  \"root\" (%s) node has no \"pos\" value, exiting\n", center.name);
    exit (1);
  }
  rankSepPt[0]=72;
  if (hasAttr($G, "ranksep")) {
    rsCnt=tokens($.rankset, rankSep, ":");
  }
  // convert array to points (int)
  for (rankSep[i]) {
    if (rankSep[i] == 0.)
      rankSepPt[i]=72;
    else
      rankSepPt[i]=(int)(72*rankSep[i]);
    maxRankSepPt=rankSepPt[i];
    maxRSPindx=i;
  }
}
N{
  if ($==center) {
    x[0]=$.X;
    y[0]=$.Y;
    print("//  center/root: ", $.name, "  ", $.pos);
  } else {
    ++max;
    x[max]=$.X;
    y[max]=$.Y;
  }
}
END_G{
  int circ=0, dist[], iD, maxD, done, totalD[];
  float D;
  node_t newN;
  string  Nprefix="____Circle____";
  for (i=1; i<=max; i++) {
    iD=idistance(x[0], y[0], x[i], y[i]);
    dist[iD]++;
  }
  // find max distance in points
  for (dist[iD]) {
    if (iD>maxD)
      maxD=iD;
  }

  wantOffset=1;
//  wantOffset=0;
  if (wantOffset) {
    print("//  offset adjust ");
    forr (rankSepPt[i]) { // note forr
      rankSepPt[i+1]=rankSepPt[i];
    }
    rankSepPt[0]=rankSepPt[1]/2;
    maxRSPindx++;
  }

  // add to or remove from rankSepPt, if necessary
  totalD[0]=0;
  done=0;
  totalD[-1]=0;  // yuck
  for (i=0; i<=maxRSPindx; i++) { // skip 1st?
    //print("//  i: ", i, "  rankSepPt: ",rankSepPt[i], "  max: ", maxRSPindx, "  done: ",done);
    if (done) { // delete these ring entries
      unset(rankSepPt,i);
    } else {
      totalD[i]=totalD[i-1]+rankSepPt[i];  // now have total distance
      if ((totalD[i]+5)>maxD) { // delete the rest
        done=1;
        maxRSPindx=i;
        //print("// DONE");
      } else if (i==maxRSPindx) {
        // this is cheesy, but keep adding entries,
        // we will strip unneeded when we are done
        rankSepPt[++maxRSPindx]=rankSepPt[i];
        //print ("//  maxRSPindx: ",maxRSPindx,"  ",rankSepPt[maxRSPindx],"  ",rankSepPt[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  unset(totalD,-1);  // unyuck

  for (totalD[i]) {
    print("//  distance count: ", totalD[i]);
    circ++;
    newN=node($G, Nprefix + (string)circ);
    newN.shape="circle";
    newN.style="solid";
    newN.style="dashed";
    newN.label="";
    newN.pos=(string)x[0] + "," + (string)y[0];
    newN.width=totalD[i]/36;
  }
}
```

The new input:

```
graph {
// changed root references
// set rank attribute for every node (undefined for nodes, but legal)

graph [root="_root"] // arbitrary, but unused name

a [ shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue" rank=1]
b [ shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue" rank=1]
c [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue" rank=2]
d [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue" rank=2]
e [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue" rank=3]
f [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue" rank=3]
g [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue" rank=2]
h [shape = circle, style=filled, fillcolor = "lightblue" rank=3]

a -- c
a -- d
a -- f
c -- e
b -- f
b -- g
b -- h
g -- h
}
```

The command line (Linux - Windows should be similar?)

```
f=sociogram2.gv; 
T=png;
F=`basename -s .gv $f`;
gvpr -cf setTwopiRanks.gvpr $f| twopi |gvpr -cf twopiCircles.gvpr|neato -n2 -T$T >$F.$T
```

Finally, the result:
[image]

Comment: First of all, than you for the enormous help you gave. I honestly had no idea this could be so complicated. I updated my question by adding details of the only bug I'm finding at the moment in your code, which is that it doesn't work if more than 10 nodes are provided. In the meanwhile I rewarded you the bounty for the obvious effort you put into helping me.