# How to open a graphviz(dot) file on vscode windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, graphviz, decision-tree, image-graphviz

I can't open a dot file on vscode in windows 10 even after I have installed in graphviz by Stephanvs extension.

Comment: You can try using the approach followed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412323/separate-edge-arrows-in-python-networkx-directed-graph/61412440#61412440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get **João Pinto's Graphviz extension**